# Apply force to entering nodes only in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am using a force directed layout in D3 with an option to pause it. However, I want to layout entering nodes even if the rest of the graph should remain static. I tried applying the force algorithm to the entering nodes like so:

```
nnodes = vis.selectAll(".node")
  .data(updatedData.nodes)
nlinks = vis.selectAll(".link")
  .data(updatedData.links)

// apply graphics to entering nodes and links

force
  .nodes(nnodes.enter())
  .links(nlinks.enter())
  .start()
force.on("tick", tick)
```

where `tick` sets node and link positions correctly when applied to the full graph or when the user is dragging nodes.

However, with the code above, the new nodes do not move beyond their initial positions.

Can I somehow apply the force algorithm to entering nodes only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force layout computes node positions by taking into account *all* nodes and links. You can't really apply it to just parts of a graph. So what you need to do is modify the nodes and links for the existing force layout instead of giving it just the new ones. To make the nodes that are already there stay where they are, try setting the `fixed` property on them.

Your code would look something like this:

```
nodes.forEach(function(n) { n.fixed = true; });

// update graphics

newNodes.forEach(function(n) { nodes.push(n); });
// add new links similarly

force.start();
```

Comment: This makes my plan more difficult that I thought. Do I understand correctly that the methods `nodes` and `links` on force are basically just telling d3 what variable the nodes/links are stored in and not necessarily what nodes should be affected by the force? To some degree it makes sense, I guess, since the other nodes should probably be exercising their force as usual, just not move themselves, i.e. be `fixed`.

Comment: No, `nodes` and `links` tell D3 what the force layout should act on. This is not the same as the nodes/links that are drawn -- this is taken care of separately.